# jQuery animate scrollTop goes up then back down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that checks if there are any errors on the page and auto scrolls to them. The problem that I'm having is it scrolls up to them but then comes back down to where it was before. I'd like it to scroll up and stay there.

```
$(".submit_button").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var errorElements = $(".error").filter(":visible");

        if (errorElements.size() > 0) {
            target_top = $(errorElements).offset().top;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target_top
            }, 800);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: This code looks good. I think something else in your code brings it down again. Do you have any other such codes to scroll to particular location ? And also does the submit button is inside any anchor tag ?

Comment: No, I don't use any auto scrolling anywhere else, and it's not inside an anchor tag.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a [Propagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) issue? Or possibly a duplicate run issue? I would suggest, first commenting everything but `return false;` out. Then check what happens when you click. If nothing, you confirm you're possibly in right area. Next, you can try and determine if the double fire is in the `click>animate` call by using the callback method. Simply put something like `}, 800, function(){ console.debug("currently called on element:\t", $(this)); });` at the end of your animate args; then check your dev toolz. (HINT: it's calling twice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your selector. I know why it's done. Any web dev that's been in this long enough has been using that for as much cross browser compat as possible, and yet still encountered this issue. The problem is, you're calling `animate:scroll` on 2 items consecutively using this selector.

The better way, in short, would be to check if it is a `WebKit` browser or not. Reason being is that non-WebKit tend to use `html` whereas *WebKit* browsers tend to use `body` <sub>*(and sometime `html`)*</sub>. This can cause such confusion as you face now.

The simple short term solution is to use something like `/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)` in your `click` callback. This will help you assign only one selector to the `animate` call.

## Example

```
var selector = /WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? 'body' : 'html';
$(selector).animate( // ...
```

---

### Test Snippet

```js
$(function() {
 // simply to make filler divs for scrolling
 for (var i=0;i<10;i++) $('<div />', { 'id': 'div'+i, 'style': 'background-color: '+String.randColorHex()+';' }).append($('.temp').clone().removeClass('temp')).height($(window).height()).appendTo($('body'));
 /*------------------------------------------*/
 
 /***S*O*L*U*T*I*O*N***/
 var divID = 0;
 function btnCheck() { // IGNORE, simply to turn buttons on and off when reaching end
  $('#btnScrollDown').prop('disabled', divID>=9);
  $('#btnScrollUp').prop('disabled', divID<=0);
 }
 
 $(document)
  .on('click', '#btnScrollDown', function() {
   if (divID < 10) {
    divID++;
    // broke everything down so it's easy to see. You can shorten this in a few ways.
/*THIS HERE-> */var selector = /WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? 'body' : 'html',
     scrollSelector = '#div' + (divID),
     scrollTop = $(scrollSelector).offset().top
     props = { scrollTop: scrollTop },
     time = 800;
    $(selector).animate(props, time);
    // simply to turn buttons on and off when reaching end
    btnCheck();
   }
  })
  .on('click', '#btnScrollUp', function() {
   if (divID > 0) {
    divID--
    // broke everything down so it's easy to see. You can shorten this in a few ways.
/*THIS HERE-> */var selector = /WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? 'body' : 'html',
     scrollSelector = '#div' + (divID),
     scrollTop = $(scrollSelector).offset().top
     props = { scrollTop: scrollTop },
     time = 800;
    $(selector).animate(props, time);
    // simply to turn buttons on and off when reaching end
    btnCheck();
   }
  });
 
});
```

```css
html, body, div { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; }
.buttons { display: inline-block; left: 1em; position: fixed; text-align: center; top: 1em; }
button { margin: .25em; padding: .1em .3em; width: 100%; }
.temp { dislpay: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/JDMcKinstry/String.randColorHex/0c9bb2ff/String.randColorHex.js"></script>
<section class="buttons">
  <button id="btnScrollUp" disabled>Scroll To Next Div Up</button><br />
  <button id="btnScrollDown">Scroll To Next Down</button>
  <sub><i>this isn't fully managed, only use buttons to scroll!</i></sub>
</section>
<table class="temp"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```